# NpgsqlConnection : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: npgsql

I am getting error '**Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**' when connecting to PostgreSQL db from .net console application. As far as I did R&D and tried different things, I found that it may be because of = in password as other connection string works fine that doesn't have = in password. Is there any way to pass = in password tried sending %3D instead of = but it didn't work. Password is **abc=xyz**. Issue looks like with Password=abc=xyz, tried changing it to Password=abc%3Dxyz as well. pgcon.Open();   gives this error.

```
string pgconnectionstring="Server=someserver.azure.com;Username=dev@postgres;Database=dbname;Port=5432;Password=abc=xyz;SSLMode=Require";
                
using (NpgsqlConnection pgcon = new NpgsqlConnection(pgconnectionstring))
{
    pgcon.Open();               
}
```

NpgsqlConnection doesn't have property password to be set from outside, Is there any way to handle = or other special chars or set password differently?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not because of =, It was because of DB name. Seems like DB name should be case sensitive. The actual db name is Field-Service. And I was setting it like Field-service, s in small which led to the issue. Though exception message led to wrong direction as it gave error connection closed by remote which generally comes in case of wrong password instead should have given something like DB doesn't exists.